# how can do thats 2 sql request in one

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, arraylist

I have these 2 requests

```
if (prix1=="" && prixe2=="") {

    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    al.AddRange((from prodname in pms_data_.produit
        where prodname.desgnation == Desg || 
              prodname.labo.labo1 == Labo || 
              prodname.rayon.rayon1 == Ra || 
              prodname.Formf.form == FORM || 
              prodname.code == CODBARRE 
        select prodname).ToList());

    return al;
}
else
{
    int p1 = Convert.ToInt32(prix1);
    int p2 = Convert.ToInt32(prixe2);

    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    al.AddRange((from prodname in pms_data_.produit
        where prodname.desgnation == Desg || 
              prodname.labo.labo1 == Labo || 
              prodname.rayon.rayon1 == Ra || 
              prodname.Formf.form == FORM || 
              prodname.code == CODBARRE || 
              prodname.ppv >=p1 && prodname.ppv <=p2
        select prodname).ToList());

    return al;
```

So the condition if the price is null I need to import data from database and if the price not null I need to import this data from database continent the price.

How can I do that with one request instead of 2?

Comment: You would only be calling the DB once, you have it wrapped in a if, else statement only one condition will run, do you mean what do you do if for example: if (prix1 !="" && prixe2=="") and vise versa?

Comment: I would either apply the Where conditionally to the IQueryable before calling ToList, or alternatively set p1 = int.MinValue and p2 = int.MaxValue when filtering does not apply

Comment: I need to replace if and else wiht the condition in request

Answer (score 1):

Biscuits had a good idea [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327752/how-can-do-thats-2-sql-request-in-one#comment62174832_37327752): conditionally apply a `Where` clause. This will result in just a single DB query, reduces repeated code, and keeps the code clear.

```
var query = from prodname in pms_data_.produit
            where prodname.desgnation == Desg || 
                  prodname.labo.labo1 == Labo || 
                  prodname.rayon.rayon1 == Ra || 
                  prodname.Formf.form == FORM || 
                  prodname.code == CODBARRE 
            select prodname;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prix1) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(prixe2)) {
    int p1 = Convert.ToInt32(prix1);
    int p2 = Convert.ToInt32(prixe2);

    query = query.Where(prodname => prodname.ppv >= p1 && prodname.ppv <= p2);
}

return new ArrayList(query.ToList());
```

I switched it to use `IsNullOrEmpty`, which is more likely to be the intended behavior.

If possible, you should migrate away from using the obsolete [`ArrayList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and start using `List<T>`, e.g. `List<Produit>` or via the interface `IList<Produit>`. The lack of generics on `ArrayList` makes it harder to work with, plus it's slower than newer options. Then your return code becomes

```
return query.ToList();
```

Comment: good idea But in the case I dont  enter any data in the first query so I dont enter no labo no desgnatio no ... 
I enter just the the price I think the result will be nothing